# How can I get a particular element with JavaScript if there are many with same class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code. How can I get `'a'` of `'div1'`:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help. Just started learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
document.querySelector('#div1 > .a');
```

- `#` is the [ID selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors); `#div` matches the element with `id="div1"`
- `>` is the [child selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)
- `.` is the [class selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html); `.a` matches any element with `class="a"`

Together, this specifically selects the `<div class="a">` element that is a child of `<div id="div1">`.